# Programming Questions / Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

Good day All,

This is my first time posting to this forum and kind off my last resort as I would've liked to figure it out myself. I am trying to create a soil moisture probe which can be used on farms to determine soil moisture at different depths. The project consists of a Arduino Nano, a DIY capacitive moisture reading setup (schematic attached- My setup is the same except for the LED moisture indicator)) and an LCD screen to display the required value.

My initial setup was a Arduino Nano (328P Old Bootloader) with a resistive soil moisture sensor. However, these sensors (as they are resistive) do not give reliable readings when measuring at different spots in a field. I believe it is largely influenced by pH, salt content etc.

My next approach was to build a DIY capacitive soil moisture sensor. After searching the web I came across a setup on hackster.io ( https://www.hackster.io/Pedro52/arduino-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor-diy-with-esp32-d7ad72 ) where a signal is sent via a ESP 32 microcontroller to a probe in the soil and a signal is returned. I implemented the same setup with the same components however I only used optimization of the timers on the Nano to generate the PWM wave (Once again this code was also obtained from another website and I am still a bit confused on how the code works).

I seem to get a reading from the sensor but the zero value seems to very volatile. Even if the wire is only picked up, the output reading changes. Is there a way to get around this and can someone please help me to get my system working optimally.

It would be highly appreciated.

[image]

```
 /

    /The setup uses a Chinese Arduino Nano, a 10M ohm, a 10k ohm, a 1N4007 diode and a 1 microfarrad capacitor as shown in the schematic.
    //The LED moisture indicator in the schematic can be ignored
    
    //#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
    //#include <LcdBarGraphRobojax.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    
    //LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd = LiquidCrystal_I2C(0x27, 16, 2);
    //LcdBarGraphRobojax lbg(&lcd, 16, 0, 0);
    
    
    float Moistlevel = 0;
    float Moistpin = A1;
    float Moisture = 0;
    float RESET;
    float factor;
    const byte CLOCKOUT = 9;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  TCCR1A = bit (COM1A0);                  //Code which I obtained to initiate the onboard timer 1 to give a signal through D9
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (CS10);
  OCR1A =  0;                             // Apparently this should be changed for prescaling. Is it necessary?


  RESET = analogRead(Moistpin);           // Take a initial reading to zero the setup

  for (int j = 1; j < 5 ; j++)            // Take another 5 readings of which the average will be determined
  {
    RESET = RESET + analogRead(Moistpin);
    delay(200);
  };

  RESET = RESET / 6;

  Serial.print(RESET);
  Serial.println();


  Serial.print("Moistlevel");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("Moisture");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

  Moistlevel = analogRead(Moistpin);                  //Take an average reading every second

  for (int i = 1; i < 5 ; i++)
  {
    Moistlevel = Moistlevel + analogRead(Moistpin);
    delay(200);
  };

  Moistlevel = Moistlevel / 6;
  Moisture = (RESET - Moistlevel) / (RESET / 100);    //Conversion to go from a voltage reading to a percentage reading

  if (Moisture < 0)                                   //Moves the initial if a negative moisture is obtained.        
  {
    RESET = Moistlevel;
  };

  Moisture = (RESET - Moistlevel) / (RESET / 100);    //Obtains the new moisture value and prints it.

  Serial.println(Moistlevel);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(Moisture);
  Serial.println();
  delay (500);
}
```

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Touching a capacitive sensor will change its readings, that's normal. Are you sure your code is sending the right frequency to the right pin?

Comment: I have tried different signals, all without any success...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for the advice,

I have chosen to divert the whole system and rather make use of a 555 timer to sent a frequency to the measuring pins. It has been tested and seems to resolve the issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

Calling this a `capacitive` sensor may be inaccurate. And that could be the least of its problems. The "fritzing" schematic is unclear, and seems to be at odds with the explanation in [Step 4 of the description](https://www.hackster.io/Pedro52/arduino-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor-diy-with-esp32-d7ad72#toc-step-4--the-electronic-set-up-1). Fortunately, a [legible schematic was derived here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=713146.0).

The author of the [hackster.io article](https://www.hackster.io/Pedro52/arduino-capacitive-soil-moisture-sensor-diy-with-esp32-d7ad72) cites Andreas Speiss' well-known YouTube video on ["Why Most Moisture Sensors Suck"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udmJyncDvw0&feature=youtu.be)... and then proceeds to design a moisture sensor that... sucks! This design seems to "miss the point": ***dc current causes an [electrolytic reaction](https://opentextbc.ca/chemistry/chapter/17-7-electrolysis/) when the conductor is in direct contact with an electrolyte (like water and damp soil).***

Wrt the OP's comment that touching the wire changes the output reading: It's almost certain that there is more capacitance in the lead wire than there is in the "fondue forks". According to the article, audio cable was the author's choice for transfer of a 600 kHz signal from his breadboard to the sensor. The *long-ish* lead wires to the sensor strike me as an odd choice.

I've been more than a little critical of this hackster.io project. But of course I may have overlooked something important - I make mistakes each and every day. If someone cares to point out any mistakes I've made here, I'll be glad to revise or delete this post. Until then, ***my proposed answer is to find a better DIY project.***

Nevertheless - you **are** on the right track by deciding to build a ***capacitive*** moisture sensor. Unless the "fondue forks" are insulated to render them non-conductive when immersed in the soil/water electrolyte, this is not a capacitive sensor - it is resistive. And its flaws may go even deeper. Another DIY guide may yield better results.

For anyone interested, an [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) simulation of the [sensor circuitry](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=713146.0) may provide insights into its operation. In one case, the sensor is modeled as a purely capacitive device (i.e. the "Fondue Forks" are insulated to prevent dc current from flowing through the soil), and in the second case as an R-C circuit (i.e. the "Fondue Forks" are un-insulated, and dc current flows through the soil). The values for Rw2 and C2/C1 were based on measurements I made with a similar sensor:

[image]

I made the following observations using this model of the sensor:

1. the time constant for the RC filter on the sensor output may be substantially longer than necessary.
2. Note the dc current flow through Rw2 averages ~ 0.18mA. Knowledge of this value will allow use of [Faraday's Law of Electrolysis](https://www.finishing.com/faqs/faradayslaw.shtml) to estimate how much of the [chrome plating](https://hcsplating.com/about/plating-faq/) will be dissolved in your soil over time.
3. The value of Rw2 largely determines the value of the output voltage; the value of the capacitance plays a much smaller role. Thus, this sensor is mostly *resistive* rather than *capacitive*.

The LTspice `.asc` file follows; all feedback welcomed:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 908 720
WIRE 336 32 288 32
WIRE 352 32 336 32
WIRE 512 32 432 32
WIRE 288 80 288 32
WIRE 336 80 336 32
WIRE 416 80 336 80
WIRE 512 80 512 32
WIRE 512 80 480 80
WIRE 512 96 512 80
WIRE 160 208 128 208
WIRE 288 208 288 144
WIRE 288 208 240 208
WIRE 480 208 288 208
WIRE 288 288 288 272
WIRE 288 288 128 288
WIRE 480 288 288 288
WIRE 288 304 288 288
WIRE 320 368 272 368
WIRE 336 368 320 368
WIRE 512 368 416 368
WIRE 272 400 272 368
WIRE 320 416 320 368
WIRE 416 416 320 416
WIRE 512 416 512 368
WIRE 512 416 480 416
WIRE 512 432 512 416
WIRE 160 528 128 528
WIRE 272 528 272 464
WIRE 272 528 240 528
WIRE 384 528 272 528
WIRE 464 528 384 528
WIRE 272 608 272 592
WIRE 272 608 128 608
WIRE 384 608 272 608
WIRE 464 608 384 608
WIRE 272 624 272 608
FLAG 288 304 0
FLAG 272 624 0
FLAG 480 208 Vsensor1
FLAG 464 528 Vsensor2
FLAG 512 96 0
FLAG 512 432 0
FLAG 288 32 Vout-insul
FLAG 272 368 Vout-unins
SYMBOL voltage 128 192 M0
WINDOW 3 -172 139 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 3.3 0 20n 20n 833.5n 1667.0n)
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL voltage 128 512 M0
WINDOW 3 -140 138 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 3.3 0 20n 20n 833.5n 1667.0n)
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL cap 256 528 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 80.0p
SYMBOL res 368 512 R0
SYMATTR InstName Rw2
SYMATTR Value 5000
SYMBOL res 256 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rs1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 256 512 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName Rs2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 272 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 80.0p
SYMBOL diode 304 144 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4007
SYMBOL diode 288 464 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value 1N4007
SYMBOL res 448 16 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL res 432 352 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL cap 480 64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 10.0n
SYMBOL cap 480 400 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 10.0n
TEXT 96 696 Left 1 !* .tran 0 2m 1.99m\n.tran 0 50.0m 49.99m
TEXT 312 168 Left 2 ;Insulated "Fondue Forks"
TEXT 288 488 Left 2 ;Non-insulated "Fondue Forks"
RECTANGLE Normal 256 184 640 316 2
RECTANGLE Normal 256 508 640 628 2
```

Comment: Seems the [OP cross-posted this question here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=713146.0) & got some answers.